# How to format a JSON in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

create a json file
the file should be formatted like this:

```json
 {"name": "YOU", 
    "items": {
    "item 1": "bread", 
        "quantity of item 1": 2, 
        "price of item1": "0.60", 
    "item 2": "milk", 
        "quantity of item 2": 10, 
        "price of item2": "6.00"
    }
}

//I tried to use f.write(
```

When I tried to create a dictionary and add a the new line operator it would just add \n to the file

```py
order = {"name": name, "items": {}}
a= 1
for i in items:
    
     order["items"].update({f'item {a}': i.item, +'\n' f'quantity of item {a}': i.quantity,+'\n' f'price of item{a}': i.price()})
     a+=1
```

Comment: Your JSON file is not in a correct format. `items` should be a dictionary. Also you need comma at the end of every key-value pair

Comment: Maybe the thing you need is dict array for `items` like `'items': [{'item': 'item1', 'price': 10}, {'item': 'item2', 'price': 20'}]` you can also append new dict data to `items`

Answer (score 1):

Python has the `json` library for formatting dictionaries into json formats:

```py
import json
json_string = json.dumps(items)
print(json_string)
```

Another issue is that you're defining key-value pairs within a list - you want to use `{}` instead of `[]` if you're giving values keys as well, and placing commas in some missed lines:

```json
{
    "name": "name",
    "items": {
        "item name": "item1",
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": 1.00
    }
}
```

Comment: I am writing this dictionary to a JSON file and the code for that is:

if(os.path.exists(f'order{name}.txt')):
    with open(f'order{name}.json', 'a') as f:
        
        f.write(json.dumps(order))
else:
    with open(f'order{name}.json', 'w') as f:
       
        f.write(json.dumps(order))


I'm sorry that the code block is not formatted properly, this is my first time using stack overflow so I am sorry about that.

Comment: File mode 'a' also creates a new file if it doesn't exist already, so you don't need the if-else statment, just with. Also, json has a `dump` method to write to a file, so instead of  `f.write(json.dumps(order))`, you can use `json.dump(order, f)`